# Виртуализация базы данных

Tags: база-данных, виртуализация

Компания, в которой я прохожу практику сейчас занимается написанием плагина для виртуализации базы данных, в сети не слишком много информации по этой теме, хотелось бы спросить, мог ли бы кто-то суммировать что это, зачем это надо, какие преимущества есть у этого подхода. Заранее благодарен

p.s. компания использует oracle и postgreSQL базы данных.

Comment: Плагина для чего?

Comment: на сколько я понял, плаин который сохраняет написанные на sql функции в бд